# Metadata not loading on Opensea

Tags: solidity, ipfs, nft, opensea

I am trying to upload my nft collection to Opensea with Hashlips. I'm not a developer.

**The image of every single nft in the collection never appears** no matter how long I wait or refresh the metadata. Images and metadata are loaded on pinata.cloud.

EDIT: I had to make a new one, becaue I lost my data. I have the same problem as usual.

**Here is the ipfs part:**

> "ipfs://QmPcTBUMrjKMUcDD1iT2FZo8QyrVfxQX6WLmePESSSgcNE/".

Can somebody give me a heads-up?

Comment: What's the metadata url?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you mean. This? QmPcTBUMrjKMUcDD1iT2FZo8QyrVfxQX6WLmePESSSgcNE or this: https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0xe3c8454ec43203f4e665fa06797aa6bafc4e834b/1

Comment: You want to go to the etherscan contract page, read contract, tokenURI and call it with a token id. Then make sure whatever data there looks right

Comment: Thanks. When I do call it, it doesn't look right. It doesn't find what it's supposed to.

Comment: Any idea on what I could do now?

Comment: You want to make sure that method gives a link to the token metadata

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "image" in the json file to "file_url".

"main.js", line 136:

```
image: `${baseUri}/${_edition}.png`,
↓
file_url: `${baseUri}/${_edition}.png`,
```

"main.js", line 152:

```
image: `${_edition}.png`,
↓
file_url: `${_edition}.png`,
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried, but to no avail.